# I'm wanting to know the name of a mathematical method to find out what is the most profitable range of certain values

Tags: terminology, recreational-mathematics, education

To be able to find the most profitable range, I add the lowest value I want to the highest value I want, with that I create a table like this example:

[image]

As you can see, the most profitable range in this example is when sum the results from 4 to 10.

I'm trying to figure out what the mathematical name for this type of search is, because I'm looking for methods to get to this result without having to do it one by one, but for that I need to know the name of what I'm looking for.

Maybe I couldn't be clear, but for example:

if John has 3 eggs and can make 10 pancakes, how many pancakes can Mary make if she has 5 eggs?

To reach this result we use the rule of three.

And that's what I'm looking for, what's name it called?

Note: The pancake example was just to explain what I was looking for, which would be the name mathematical `rule of three`.

Comment: I don't see the relationship between the spreadsheet and the pancake question. It looks like you are asking in the spreadsheet: for $a_0=50,a_1=5,a_2=-20,\dots,a_{10}=9$, what choice of $m$ and $n$ ($n>m$) maximises $$ \sum_{i=m}^n a_i$$

Comment: Hello @A.M. , first of all, thanks for support, so the pancake example was just to explain what I was looking for, which would be the mathematical name "rule of three". And in the case of what I'm wanting in the table, what would the name be? Understood? Because for me to look up methods to get this result from spreadsheet formulas, I need to know the name of what I'm looking for.

Comment: The formula for what you are doing is just max(range)+min(range).  It doesn't have a name that I know of as it doesn't seem to be a very useful measurement.

Comment: I searched for the ```most profitable range``` but found nothing in relation to it, so I believe the name is different.

Comment: Hello @Alan , thanks for support, the usefulness is because I make investments according to the advantage that exists between one team and another, so I'm looking for the most profitable range of advantage to invest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem "given $a_0,a_1,\dots,a_n\in \mathbb{Z}$, find $0\le j<k\le n$ such that $\sum_{i=j}^k a_i$ is maximised" is called the "maximum subarray problem" or "maximum consecutive subsequence sum" problem or something similar.

Your naive approach requires $(n+1)^2/2\in O(n^2)$ calculations, which is not too bad.

Kadane's algorithm is $O(n)$: see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem) or [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/largest-sum-contiguous-subarray/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for support mate!